# What is the center of lorentz contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I'm a highschool physics student with basic undergrad knowledge, and according to griffith E&M, it seems like the center of contraction is dependent on the specific coordinate system you choose. However, it seems more "correct" that this should be irrelevent to where you choose as your origin as long as you are moving at the same speed. What is the correct way of understanding lorentz contraction?

Comment: What do you mean by center of contraction?

Comment: The choice of origin is indeed arbitrary, however this is called Poincaré invariance rather than Lorentz invariance. Lorentz contraction just tells you that moving objects shrink in size

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any absolute centre of contraction. The Lorenz contraction means that if you take any two fixed points in one frame, the distance between them in that frame will be greater than the distance between them at a point in time in any other frame in which they are moving along the line that joins them.

To make it easier to visualise, suppose there is a line 5m long in its rest frame, with a left hand end and a right hand end as you look at it go past you. Let's suppose that its relative speed is such that from your perspective it is contracted to 4m long. The 'centre of contraction' is arbitrary, depending on where you place your origin for making measurements. If you place your origin at the midpoint of the line at a given instant, each end will be 2m away from it, so the line will seem to have shrunk in by 0.5m from both ends. If you place your origin at the left hand end at a given instant, the right hand end will appear to have shrunk in by 1m.

The contraction is actually the result of the relativity of simultaneity. The reason why you consider the two end-points of the line to be 4m apart is because you are considering them at two separate moments in the rest frame of the line, so one end of the line has had a chance to move 1m closer to where the other was a moment beforehand.

Comment: Isn't it then, that the line would end up in different places depending on where I place my origin?

Comment: No! The choice of origin doesn't change the location of points- it only changes the value of the labels (coordinates) you use to specify their locations.